# Angularjs depending on parent scope

Tags: angularjs

While building an application using AngularJs I asked my self if the following is good practice

I have "AppController" and every other controller is child of it. AppController has something like this.

```
$scope.layout = { sidebar: false, searchbar: true};
```

Now, child controllers should be able to change these values:

```
$rootScope.sidebar = true;
```

In this case, my child module is totally dependent on root controller and if I want this child controller works inside some other application I have to make sure parent controller of that other app always have $scope.layout object. Is this good practice? Would it be better to build layout module used by both, parent and child controllers? Like code bellow:

```
angular.module("app.ui", [])
  .factory("Layout", [function(){
     var _sidebar = false;
     var searchbar = true;


     var sidebar = function(flag){
        if(flag !== undefined) _sidebar = flag;
        return _sidebar;
     }

     var searchbar = function(flag){
        if(flag !== undefined) _searchbar = flag;
        return _searchbar;
     }

return {
   sidebar : sidebar,
   searchbar : searchbar
}
}])
```

Comment: if you want to build very modular and adaptive Apps, I would suggest you try out the directive controller. They have own scopes and you can reuse them in nearly every context.

Comment: I think it is better in your second option, by using service to  build your global variable.

Comment: Do whatever you find to be easiest to maintain. Every proposed implementation in the OP is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst there may be other architectural approaches to what you want to do (e.g. look into the documentation on the *scope* property of directive declarations and its facilities for binding specific properties in the parent scope using @, = and &), generally Services are indeed a good option for sharing access to common data. You could simplify it a bit, if you don't have extra logic that must happen when the values are updated:

```
angular.module("app.ui", [])

.service("Layout", function() {
  this.sidebar = false;
  this.searchbar = true;
})
```

If you inject this service into your controllers and add it to their scope, you can update it and listen for changes like this:

```
.controller("AppCtl", function($scope, Layout) {
  $scope.Layout = Layout;

  // Method called by a search button, say
  $scope.search = function() {
    Layout.searchbar = true;
  }

  $scope.$watch("Layout.searchbar", function(newVal, oldVal) {
    // Do something in this scope if value has been changed from elsewhere
  });

});
```

Comment: I used Tim solution. Not sure if should mark it as answer since there are many solutions for this and I just used this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach where you create a directive which triggers the scroll on click.
[Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/mjGE9GOQFUzGzQqYVFAw/preview)